# Importing mysql dump from another host, what to keep on the current one?

Tags: mysql

I will be importing a MySQL dump from another host with lots of DBs in it to the new server I just set up with VestaCP.
Since that seems to overwrite everything on the current one should I keep the current mysql tables or any other of the ones vesta creates?

If not where I should update the root password which is different in the dump i will be importing?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify. Are you dumping *all* databases including the `mysql` database (the one containing meta data)? What are your dump commands? And what is your intention? You're moving your databases to another server?

Comment: yes.
I'm doing
mysqldump -u root -p -QqeR --add-drop-table --all-databases | bzip2 -v9 - > siteData.sql.bz2

The idea is to move all the databases to a new server, where i've rsynced the site files already with the final intent everything to work without changing db users, passwords or whatever since we are talking 100+ sites here.

The old host was using no CP, the new one VestaCP.

Comment: You should edit your post with the extra information. You should also specify which distribution you're moving from and to.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which distribution, so this is for Debian-based:

If you import everything, including the 'mysql' database and restart MySQL, you will have imported (and overwritten!) users from your old DB as well, as you stated. There are several things to keep in mind:

- Test it.
- Use long options when posting here. `--events` and `--routines` is clearer that -R and -E (the latter you missed).
- if you have a `~/.my.cnf` or any other config file which specifies the (root) password, change it.
- `/etc/mysql/debian/cnf` contains the user account that the debian package manager uses to maintain your database server. That password will no longer work, so you will have to copy the password from that file on your old server. If your old server was not Debian-based and there is no `debian-sys-maint` account, you may need to create one with `SUPER` privileges.

I don't know what VestaCP does. You may want to dump its DB first and re-import it after your transfer.

Comment: Ah good points, make it much more clearer.
I migrate from CentOS to Ubuntu

I guess would be easier to import everything but the mysql db, and then manually export everything but the root users from it and import to the fresh mysql one?

Comment: That's possible, but you also have to import the grants. It can get tricky.

Comment: Is there a way to merge them then?
What would be the easiest way you suggest?